# HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization. Trying to build Spring boot application using MySQL docker image

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a application using Spring boot and MySQL.
The application is running successfully when working on local server, but when try to trying to create docker image the service is throwing Exception during pool initialization error.

Below are my project config
Spring boot version: 3.0.1
Java version: 17
MySQL version: 8

**application properties**

```
server.port=3005
spring.application.name=user-service
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/bank_app?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysqldb
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bank_app
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - main-network
  user-service:
    build:
      context: ../code/user-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: user-service
    container_name: user-service
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    ports:
      - 3005:3005
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=user-service
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"eureka":{"client":{"serviceUrl":{"defaultZone":"http://eureka-service:8761/eureka"}}}}
    networks:
      - main-network
networks:
  main-network:
    external:
      name: main-network
volumes:
  db:
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I tried by replacing the **localhost** with container name **mysqldb** in the datasource URL but still I'm facing same error

**Issue**

```
2023-02-14 22:44:07 2023-02-14T17:14:07.221Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 3005 (http)
2023-02-14 22:44:07 2023-02-14T17:14:07.292Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-14 22:44:07 2023-02-14T17:14:07.293Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
2023-02-14 22:44:08 2023-02-14T17:14:08.255Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-14 22:44:08 2023-02-14T17:14:08.294Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 18593 ms
2023-02-14 22:44:10 2023-02-14T17:14:10.390Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-02-14 22:44:11 2023-02-14T17:14:11.085Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
2023-02-14 22:44:13 2023-02-14T17:14:13.010Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2023-02-14 22:44:13 2023-02-14T17:14:13.810Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-02-14 22:44:15 2023-02-14T17:14:15.664Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2023-02-14 22:44:15 
2023-02-14 22:44:15 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2023-02-14 22:44:15 
2023-02-14 22:44:15 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar!/:6.1.6.Final]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar!/:6.1.6.Final]
2023-02-14 22:44:15 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar!/:6.1.6.Final]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your port mapping for `mysqldb` is maybe not needed? That is unless you really want to expose MySQL's server to the outside world (`outside:inside`). In your case on port 3307.

```
ports:
  - 3307:3306
```

I'm not sure if you really mean to expose your server, but inside of your container you should be using the real port, `localhost:3306`.

Comment: Yes, I changed the port to 3306 and my URL is now calling at **jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/bank_app?useSSL=false**